# How to clip border of ConicalGradient

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create radar animation with using Qt/Qml.
But i cannot clip borders of ConicalGradient.
Tried to use Shape, ShapePath. But it's not give to me a good result.
Just can't clip borders of ConicalGradient, tried to use with 45 angle, result is not good.

```
MapQuickItem {
        id: radarItem

       

     
        coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(someLatitude, someLongitude)
        zoomLevel: 16

        sourceItem: Rectangle {
          id: radarLen

          clip: true
          color: "transparent"

         
          height: 1300
          radius: height / 2

          visible: model.state === "rx"
          width: height
          x: -height / 2
          y: -height / 2

          transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: height / 2
            origin.y: height / 2

            NumberAnimation on angle {
              duration: 1000
              from: 0
              loops: Animation.Infinite
              // property: "rotation"
              running: true
              // target: radarLen
              to: 360
            }
          }

          ConicalGradient {
            anchors.fill: parent
            angle: 90

            gradient: Gradient {
              GradientStop {
                color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
                position: 0.0
              }
              GradientStop {
                color: Qt.rgba(0, 50, 0, 0.1)
                position: 1.0
              }
            }
          }

          Rectangle {
            id: radarInside

            color: model.isAttacked ? "red" : "green"
            height: 5
            width: radarLen.height / 2
            x: width
            y: width
          }
        }
      }
```

here you can see, what i take.

[image]

I'm expected something like this.

[image: expected result.]

Comment: Did you try using an **OpacityMask**?

Comment: Nope, but i don't think that it could help in my question.

Comment: If someone suggests something, it is better to give it a try so that others can understand your question better. It is considered rude to respond in such a manner. By the way, what I suggested is working and I HAVE TRIED IT!

Comment: Damn, please excuse me, I didn’t know I could be rude this way. I'm sorry I was rude to you.

Comment: I need read more information about stackoverflow rules and good tone on stackoverflow, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

smr's right. Correct application of `OpacityMask` would solve this problem. The key features of `OpacityMask` are:

- the source component is declared on the page, but is invisible
- the maskSource component is also declared on the page, but is also invisible
- both source and maskSource are, typically, the same width and height
- `OpacityMask` also has the same width and height
- `OpacityMask` may be positioned elsewhere

Here's an example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Page {
    title: "Radar Demo"
    Radar {
        id: radar
        width: 120
        height: 120
        visible: false
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: clipCircle
        width: 120
        height: 120
        radius: 60
        visible: false
    }
    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        OpacityMask {
            width: radar.width
            height: radar.height
            implicitWidth: width
            implicitHeight: height
            source: radar
            maskSource: clipCircle
        }
    }
}

// Radar.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Item {
    width: 120
    height: 120
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        NumberAnimation on rotation {
            duration: 3000
            from: 0
            to: 360
            loops: Animation.Infinite
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 120
            width: height
            radius: height / 2
            border.color: "black"
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 80
            width: height
            radius: height / 2
            border.color: "black"
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 40
            width: height
            radius: height / 2
            border.color: "black"
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 8
            width: height
            radius: height / 2
            color: "darkcyan"
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 2
            height: 20
            color: "darkcyan"
        }
        Rectangle {
            x: -80
            y: 20
            width: 80
            height: 80
            color: "darkcyan"
            ConicalGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop {
                        color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        position: 0.0
                    }
                    GradientStop {
                        color: Qt.rgba(0, 50, 0, 0.1)
                        position: 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try this Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)